# TimepickerFragment show() method cannot be resolved

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm trying to use a dialog fragment to select dates, but the timePickerFragment.show(...)  method in the Signigicant_Other class below cannot be resolved.  The show method is suggested by the intellisense, also.  I'm unclear why It's not resolved, I'm afraid something easy that I'm just not seeing.  FYI, I followed these tutorials:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html
http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-dialogfragment-tutorial/

Activity calling the fragment:

```
package com.mycompany.dudesmyreminders;

import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;


public class Significant_Other extends ActionBarActivity {


    Button birthbutton;
    Button annibutton;
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_significant__other);


        // Locate the button in activity_main.xml


  birthbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.SignificanOther_birthButton);
        annibutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.SignificanOther_annivButton);

    // Capture button clicks
    birthbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            TimePickerFragment timePickerFragment = new TimePickerFragment();
            // Show DialogFragment
            timePickerFragment.show(fm, "Time Picker"); //THE PROBLEM IS HERE
        }

    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_significant__other, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

EDIT: SOLUTION IS THE CHANGE INDICATED BELOW

Fragment which will have the date picker:

```
package com.mycompany.dudesmyreminders;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
//Solution was to change android.app.DialogFragment; to   android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
//import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.app.TimePickerDialog;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.text.format.DateFormat;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TimePicker;

import java.util.Calendar;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Activities that contain this fragment must implement the
 * {@link TimePickerFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener} interface
 * to handle interaction events.
 */
public class TimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
        implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener{

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    public TimePickerFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current time as the default values for the picker


 final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

    // Create a new instance of TimePickerDialog and return it
    return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, hour, minute,
            DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
}

public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
    // Do something with the time chosen by the user
}



@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    try {
        mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}

/**
 * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
 * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
 * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
 * activity.
 * <p/>
 * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
 * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
 * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
 */
public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    // TODO: Update argument type and name
    public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
}

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use

```
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
```

Since you are using the SupportFragmentManager. Good luck!

Comment: I had tried adding that to Significant_other, but it marks it as unused.  Is the support.v4 used for older versions of android?

Comment: Okay.  Tried it on the DatePickerFragment, and that cleared the error.  Thanks.  Any advice as to the benefits of support.v4 versus the standard?

Comment: Added solution to my question

Comment: `FragmentManager` and `DialogFragment` require API level 11 and higher
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html

If you planning on supporting API versions lower than this, you should use the support library.